# Print 2-D matrix of list based on string matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I have a list that I would like to express in a grid based on each feature selected.

```
breakfast = [['Apple,Banana'],['Apple,Yogurt'],['Banana,Oatmeal']]
```

Desired grid:

```
Index:   Apple   Banana   Yogurt   Oatmeal
1         "x"      "x"     " "       " "
2         "x"      " "     "x"       " "
3         " "      "x"     " "       "x"
```

I think I need to use regex and string indexing of the list through the grid, how to do so is my question.  Better yet, is there a python library that does this automatically (like leaps/summary in R)?

Here is my current code:

```
def printMatrix(data):
    header = "Index:\tApple\tBanana\tYogurt\tOatmeal"
    print(header)
    for index, value in enumerate(data):
        if str(value).find('Apple') != -1:
            print(index,"\t\'X'", end='')
        else:
            print(index,"\t\' '",end='')
        if str(value).find('Banana') != -1:
            print("\t\'X'", end='')
        else:
            print("\t\' '",end='')
        if str(value).find('Yogurt') != -1:
            print("\t\'X'", end='')
        else:
            print("\t\' '")
        if str(value).find('Oatmeal') != -1:
            print("\t\'X'")
```

The results are accurate but the efficiency feels poor.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically a long series of if-else statements per category.  Strikes me that there is a more pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Set, List Comprehension & Ternary Condition plus `Pandas`

If you want Pythonic as well as pretty, here is one way.

```
import pandas as pd
breakfast = [['Apple,Banana'],['Apple,Yogurt'],['Banana,Oatmeal']]
breakfast = [i[0].split(',') for i in breakfast]


columns=list(set([j for i in breakfast for j in i]))
columns.sort()
values = [[1 if j in i else 0 for j in columns]for i in breakfast]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Apple  Banana  Oatmeal  Yogurt
0      1       1        0       0
1      1       0        0       1
2      0       1        1       0
```

Comment: I updated my post with my current code.  I'm looking for a method that "pretty prints" to the desired output if possible.

Comment: Then you may seek `pandas` which not only provide pretty prints but also other amazing reshaping and groupby functions.

Comment: I should have been more clear, the internal list elements are composed of a single string separated by commas (lists can have more than 2 elements).  This breaks the column headers.  Updating OP

Comment: @Shawn Updated. You can use `string.split(',')` with list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure pandas solution - first create `Series`, then select first value of lists to scalars by `str[0]` and last [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
breakfast = [['Apple,Banana', 'Apple,Yogurt'],['Apple,Yogurt'],['Banana,Oatmeal']]

df = pd.Series([','.join(x) for x in breakfast]).str.get_dummies(',')
print (df)
   Apple  Banana  Oatmeal  Yogurt
0      1       1        0       1
1      1       0        0       1
2      0       1        1       0
```

But if possible multiple list values solution is `list comprehension` with `join` first and then `str.get_dummies`:

```
breakfast = [['Apple,Banana', 'Apple,Yogurt'],['Apple,Yogurt'],['Banana,Oatmeal']]

df = pd.Series([','.join(x) for x in breakfast]).str.get_dummies(',')
print (df)
   Apple  Banana  Oatmeal  Yogurt
0      1       1        0       1
1      1       0        0       1
2      0       1        1       0
```

Comment: Surprised how similar my code is to the source code of `get_dummies()`!

Comment: @KenT - You can check [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/strings.py#L808) :)